# An external GPU for playing Diablo 2: Resurrected

Tags: graphics-cards

```
Dell Latitude 5580 (laptop)
Thunderbolt
Intel Core i7-7820HQ
16GB DDR4 
Nvidia Gforce 940MX
512GB SSD
Windows 10 Home
```

I have troubles running [Diablo 2 Resurrected](https://diablo2.blizzard.com/en-us/) with pretty much the lowest graphic details and I believe that this has to do with Nvidia Gforce 940MX being too "weak" for this game.

What external GPU could help me run it in a decent way (medium to high details)?

Sidenote: I mean only to standard external GPU (a product sold as external GPU, not anything that requires any kind of tweaking).

Comment: Can you add your country? we can't really give a recommendation other than "any modern external gpu will probably work"   without it.

Comment: @skippy with all niceness I don' understand why saying in which state I currently reside would help.

Comment: With which state you imply the USA, this is a website that is used internationally. so when recommending things it's good to know what's roughly available.

Answer (score 1):

Something with a GTX 1650, RTX 2060, RX 5500 or with the same letters and a higher number should do. In theory, your gpu is powerful enough to run at low settings, but with my experience in low settings on games, that ain't lookin good.

Comment: Hi, none of these cards are external.

Comment: You can get them in external gpu cases AFAIK of make your own external gpu out of them

Comment: The last option is only for tweakers

Comment: I mean to external GPU in a standard way...

Comment: You can google something like "GTX 1650 external gpu"

Comment: @lsru85 you can too, but I don't find how it's relevant if I am looking for a standard product of external GPU, no tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking around but there seem to be very few enclosures sold with an added GPU. those that are tend to come with an rtx3070 or faster, those cards are significantly faster than you would need so I wouldn't recommend them unless you really have the cash to spare.

My advice would be to look for a razer Core X like [this one](https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16814986002?Description=external%20gpu&cm_re=external_gpu-_-9SIAPCPDYH2878-_-Product&quicklink=true) or a [power color gaming station](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0792NJ8QV)

then add something like a 1660ti or an rtx2060. I've heard that many people have some issues with amd cards and e-gpu's so try to avoid those.

Comment: Thank you skippy, I really like this kind of answer. Just about those AMD cards, if OP wants to get a Mac or Linux later on, nVidia cards are harder to set up than AMD cards, so which is better depends on what OP needs in the finest details.